# Is it possible to forbid users in directly accessing files inside my folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need the user to login **FIRST**. I am currently using .htaccess and I am not sure how to configure it.

Okay, so I have searched for this problem online and all of them were actually forbidding the user even if he/she is logged in. I am not knowledgeable about configuring .htaccess so I'm sorry. Any help? :(

This is my .htaccess file that my instructor made but I am not sure where to put it. My file management is as follows:

InvSystem

```
 - admin
    - accounts
    - branch
    - css
    - index.php **Homepage
 - subadmin
 - includes
 - index.php **Login form
 - .htaccess **Idontknow where to put it
```

---

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule     ^admin/$                                admin/index.php                 [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$     index.php?p=$1&id=$2            [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$                     index.php?p=$1                  [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
RewriteRule     ^$                                      index.php?p=index               [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

Comment: how that relates to Java?

Comment: my bad sorry lol